# Uncaught TypeError:Cannot read property 'status' of undefined at XMLHttpRequest.http.onload

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, this

I'm getting the following message in the console:
`easyHTTP.js:9 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'status' of undefined at XMLHttpRequest.http.onload (easyHTTP.js:9)`

Files:

1. *easyHTTP.js*

```
function easyHTTP() {
    this.http = new XMLHttpRequest();
}

// GET request 
easyHTTP.prototype.get = function(url) {
    this.http.open('GET',url,true);
    this.http.onload = function() {
        if(this.http.status==200) {
            console.log(this.http.responseText);
        }
    }

    this.http.send();
}
```

2. app.js

```
const xhr = new easyHTTP();
xhr.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
```

Comment: You are using `this.http.status` with in function *(onload)* that is a property of the `XMLHttpRequestIntstance` already. Change `this.http.status` to `this.status` or use an arrow function. By the way... `.onload`, `xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200` already. Those properties where for past days, when we used to test for `xhr.onreadystatechange`.

Answer (score -1):

Check if READY first...

```
if((this.http.readyState==4)&&(this.http.status==200)){


}
```

Comment: It's a `this` context issue. This is not the answer.